# Import dot in xlsx as missing value in Stata

Tags: import, stata, xlsx

I have an Excel sheet as input for Stata. In the Excel, a dot in a cell marks a missing value, e.g.:

```
Column1 Column2
1       10
2       .
.       13
.       15
3       .
```

However, when importing the Excel to Stata, both columns above are identified as a String.

How can I tell Stata during the import that all dots should be recognized as missing values and thus my numeric columns remain numeric, although they include some dots/missing values?

Comment: You don't say what `import` command you are using from what kind of file. But in Stata given this set-up `destring, replace` is one solution.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you might be importing from Excel or a csv.

**Excel**
From the `import excel` guidance: 
If the column contains at least one cell with nonnumerical text, the entire column is imported as a string variable.

So the easiest solution is:
`destring` the variables. You can `destring` a whole list in one go via:

```
destring var_1 var_2 var_3, replace
```

That will overwrite the variables as numeric variables and the . will be coded as missing.

**Importing a CSV** 
As in Excel if there are non-numeric characters I believe Stata will think it might be a string. You could use the `numericcols` option when importing

```
import delimited, numericcols()
```

Then whatever columns you specify in the `numericcols` option are forced to be numeric and the . should be interpreted as missing.

Equally easy would just be still to `destring` as outlined above.